# how to connect hibernate and DB2

Tags: java, hibernate, struts, db2

I am running an application that used struts and hibernate. I am currently using Derby database.
Now i have to shift on DB2 database.

Please tell me

- what Configuration I have to do in
  hibernate configuration file?
- Do I have to set any classpath
  variable?
- I know there are two jars for DB2
  (**db2jcc.jar** & **db2jcc_license_cu.jar**).
  Is there any other jar I may need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want hibernate to manage it. Not any container. I am using JBoss server.

Comment: Thanks this problem is over but there's another. Here is the link.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/5497875/420613

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It should work with **db2jcc.jar**

Add below properties to your `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>

<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</property>

<property name="connection.url">jdbc:db2://<host>:<port50000>/<dbname></property>

<property name="connection.username">dbusername</property>

<property name="connection.password">dbpassword</property>
```

Change last 3 properties according to your configuration

Comment: please see my response in my last answer below the page.

Comment: Thanks this problem is over but there's another. Here is the link. stackoverflow.com/q/5497875/420613

Comment: You should mark the answer as correct which solved your problem.

Comment: @ImranTariq it was your complete hibernate.cfg.xml ?

Answer (score 2):

If your DB2 driver supports JDBC approach (and it does), you need to set connection properties. There are three ways of doing so: via xml, via `hibernate.properties` file and via programmatic configuration (more specifically, see [Hibernate Reference Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/pdf/hibernate_reference.pdf), chapter 1 and 2. Here is an simple example, how to do this:

Programmatically:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration()
.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver")
.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:db2://yourDbServerUrl:port/databaseName")
.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "yourUsername")
.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "yourPassword")
.buildSessionFactory();
```

Via `hibernate.properties`:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:db2://yourDbServerUrl:port/databaseName
hibernate.connection.username = yourUsername
hibernate.connection.password = yourPassword
```

Comment: please see my response in my last answer below the page.

Comment: Thanks this problem is over but there's another. Here is the link. stackoverflow.com/q/5497875/420613

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to need the driver (I don't know if the jars you have are sufficient, but it might be the case) on the classpath and set the database dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect` in your `persistence.xml`.

In JBoss it's normally only necessary to either put the driver into the server's lib directory or into the application's lib dir.

Comment: please see my response in my last answer below the page.

Comment: Thanks this problem is over but there's another. Here is the link. stackoverflow.com/q/5497875/420613