# Hibernate and DB2 data fetching

Tags: java, hibernate, struts, db2

I am using struts and hibernate application.
I have a problem while fetching records from DB2 via hibernate.

I am getting this error

```
14:22:17,804 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: -204, SQLState: 42704
14:22:17,804 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.TABLENAME, DRIVER=3.57.82
14:22:17,804 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: -727, SQLState: 56098
14:22:17,804 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-204;42704;DB2ADMIN.TABLENAME, DRIVER=3.57.82
14:22:17,804 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: -727, SQLState: 56098
14:22:17,804 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-204;42704;DB2ADMIN.TABLENAME, DRIVER=3.57.82
14:22:17,804 ERROR [VisualListAction] com.sit.exceptions.DaoException: Unable to fetch tablenameItems.
14:22:17,804 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
```

Error code 42704 means that **tableName** table does not exist. But it exists in the database.

Any idea what could be the problem? Problem with schema or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with database schema.

i was using

**schema.tableName**

when I use

**schema1.tableName**

it works. Because in DB schema was **schema1**.